# Merge 2 images in Swift without losing the size of the original image

Tags: ios, swift, image, merge, uiimage

I'm trying to merge 2 images without losing the size of the original image. 
I have a large white image and I want to merge a smaller image onto it. If I move the smaller image so that only have of it is showing on top of the larger image, then when I merge the 2 images only the half of the image that is showing should be merged and the other side should be cropped out.

Hierarchy of the image below

UIView : Clip Subviews is checked

----> UIImageView with white image

----> UIImageView : This image has a pan gesture allowing it move within the view.

[image: Before pressing the button]

I found this post [merge two different images swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996711/merge-two-different-images-swift) and tried to mask the images

```
let maskedImage: UIImage = self.maskImage(imageView.image!, withMask: whiteImage.image!)

newImageView.image = maskedImage
```

but that doesn't take into account the images current positions in the image views. It just returns the original image (which is then resized to fit the UIIMageView and that's why its a little larger than before)

[image: After pressing the button]

Does anyone know how can I merge the 2 images and take into account their positions when merging? Ideally the second image looks exactly like the first image except that's it's a single image instead of two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A reasonable technique which would give you a desired result would be to

1. Arrange the images you wish to 'merge' into a UIView.
2. Take an image snapshot of that UIView.

I like to create extensions on UIView which will snapshot an image (take a screen shot if you will). Thus:-

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {

  func capture() -> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, self.opaque, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
    self.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
  }

}
```

Once your images (as subviews) are contained by a single view you can.

```
let mergedImage = containerUIView.capture()
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating Damo's answer for Swift 3.x

```
extension UIView {    
    func capture() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, self.isOpaque, UIScreen.main.scale)
        self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}
```